# Django: Static Image Not Loading

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having issues getting an image to load on my Django web application. I have used the online documentation and tried peoples suggestions that I found on Stackoverflow but I am still not having any luck getting it to load. Here is what I have:

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_DIR =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = [STATIC_DIR,]
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from dir_app import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'dir_app'

urlpatterns=[
   path('', views.tradesmen, name='tradesmen'),
   path('register', views.register,name='register'),
   path('user_login', views.user_login,name='user_login')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Index.html: (Gist)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 {% load static %}   
  <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <img src="{% static 'dir_app/tools.png' %}">
   </body>
  </html>
```

Here is where the image is stored:

[image: location of IMAGE]

Comment: Try to add ```+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)``` in the main url, not in app urls.py

Answer (score 1):

`DEBUG` should be true if want to use `django.conf.url.static`
https://github.com/django/django/blob/926148ef019abcac3a9988c78734d9336d69f24e/django/conf/urls/static.py#L23

`STATIC_ROOT` should be a string, not a list.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT